# How to add event listener to element created dynamically within prototype?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, prototype-programming

**HTML**

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var TestClass = function() {};
TestClass.prototype = {
    addElement: function(parentId) {
    var parent = document.querySelector('#' + parentId);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = '+';
    a.href = '#';
    a.addEventListener('click', this.onElementClick, false); //nothing happens on click
    parent.innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
  },

  onElementClick: function() {
    console.log('dynamic element clicked');
  }
};

new TestClass().addElement('main'); // on DOM ready
```

**Output**

```
<div id="main"><a href="#">+</a></div>
```

Comment: Try changing `parent.innerHTML = a.outerHTML` to `parent.append(a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var TestClass = function() {};
TestClass.prototype = {
    addElement: function(parentId) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentId); //Changed to getElementById
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = '+';
    a.href = '#';
    a.addEventListener('click', this.onElementClick, false);
    parent.append(a); //Changed
  },

  onElementClick: function() {
    console.log('dynamic element clicked');
  }
};

new TestClass().addElement('main'); // on DOM ready
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

You did not add your `a` to `parent`, instead you just added its HTML.

Comment: @niksofteng No problem, please upvote and mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the event listener, correctly, however you are forgetting to add the element.

I have added `document.body.append(a)` to the `addElement` method.

This leads to the following code:

```
var TestClass = function() {};
TestClass.prototype = {
    addElement: function(parentId) {
    var parent = document.querySelector('#' + parentId);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = '+';
    a.href = '#';
    a.addEventListener('click', this.onElementClick, false);
    document.body.append(a);
    parent.innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
  },

  onElementClick: function() {
    console.log('dynamic element clicked');
  }
};

new TestClass().addElement('main'); // on DOM ready
```

[Test it out here](https://jsfiddle.net/mt8tdg7g/)

Comment: Now the parent.innerHTML=a.outerHTML is unnecessary, and you want parent.append(a); ...

Comment: I hesitate to append to body. Why body?

Comment: All visible content is either in `body` or one of its children. Just grabbed `body` as an example. Saying that, for your use case using `parent.append(a)` makes more sense (as per @Arg0n's answer).